# I'm creating a hangman game in vanilla JS, and have stumbled across this error that I can't figure out the reason for

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a hangman game in vanilla JS, and have stumbled across this error that I can't figure out the reason for.

The error says that "this.guessedLetters" is undefined in 'getStatus prototype'. I really can't figure out why that is.

here's the code:

```
const Hangman = function (word, remainingGuesses) {
    this.word = word.toLowerCase().split('')
    this.remainingGuesses = remainingGuesses
    this.guessedLetters = []
    this.status = 'playing'
}

Hangman.prototype.getStatus = function () {
    let finished = true
    this.word.forEach(function(item){
        if(this.guessedLetters.includes(item))
        finished = false
    })
    if((this.remainingGuesses === 0 || this.remainingGuesses < 0) && finished === true ){
        this.status = 'failed'
    }
    else if(!finished){
        this.status = 'finished'
    }
    else{
        this.status = 'playing'
    }

    }




Hangman.prototype.getPuzzle = function () {
    let puzzle = ''

    this.word.forEach((letter) => {
        if (this.guessedLetters.includes(letter)) {
            puzzle += letter
        } else {
            puzzle += '*'
        }
    })

    return puzzle
}



Hangman.prototype.makeGuess = function (guess) {
    guess = guess.toLowerCase()
    const isUnique = !this.guessedLetters.includes(guess)
    const isBadGuess = !this.word.includes(guess)

    if (isUnique) {
        this.guessedLetters.push(guess)
    }

    if (isUnique && isBadGuess) {
        this.remainingGuesses--
    }
}

const game1 = new Hangman('Cat', 2)

console.log(game1.getPuzzle())
console.log(game1.remainingGuesses)

document.querySelector('#godzillaX').textContent = game1.getPuzzle()
document.querySelector('#godzillaY').textContent = game1.remainingGuesses

console.log(game1.status)

window.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    const guess = e.key
    game1.makeGuess(guess)
    console.log(game1.getPuzzle())
    console.log(game1.remainingGuesses)
    document.querySelector('#godzillaX').textContent = game1.getPuzzle()
    document.querySelector('#godzillaY').textContent = game1.remainingGuesses
    game1.getStatus()
    console.log(game1.status)
})
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem. The title is the first thing potential answerers will see, and if your title isn't interesting, they won't read the rest."_

Comment: _"//it says to add more details, so please ignore the text below//..."_ - Don't cheat the system. There's a reason for those checks/rules.

Comment: Your `this.guessedLetters` points to `function(item){` and not to parent. Do `var self = this` and replace everywhere `this` with `self`. Or use fat arrow function. Scoping issue

Comment: Adding an arrow function solved the issue. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because `this` points to `function(item){` and not to the `Hangman` object instance.

I see two possible solutions:

1. Old fashion style:

```js
Hangman.prototype.getStatus = function () {
    let finished = true
    const gl = this.guessedLetters
    this.word.forEach(function(item){
        if(gl.includes(item))
        finished = false
    })
```

2. Use fat arrow so `this` will point to parent:

```js
Hangman.prototype.getStatus = function () {
    let finished = true
    this.word.forEach(item => {
        if(this.guessedLetters.includes(item))
        finished = false
    })
```